# React Native Image Picker doesn't run any ImagePicker functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using the code from the Read Me on react-native-image-picker page, but i receive an error, after it successfully installed (and i also set the correct permissions on info.plist.

When attempting to openGallery() i get the following warning and no image library opens:

**Possible unhandled Promise Rejection TypeError; undefined is not a function (near...reactNativeImagePicker.default.launchImageLibrary...)**

Here's my code:

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
.....

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    state = {
      fileURL: '',
    }
  }

   //function
   openGallery = async () => {
      const options = {
        mediaType: 'video'
      }

    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console('Response = ', response);

      if(response.didCancel){
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      }
      else{
       this.setState({ fileURL: response.uri });
      }
    });
 }

render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>      
    <Button 
       style={{margin: 20}}
       onPress={this.openGallery}
       title='Open Gallery'
       backgroundColor='blue'
    />
   </View>

);

 }   
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: did you linked ?

Comment: as in 'react-native link'? Yes i did straight after i innstalled react-native-image-picker